# Azure VMSS agent frequently turning to updating status

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-vm-scale-set, cloud-init

I have created a self hosting agent pool in AzureDevOps which uses a VMSS agent. The VMSS agent has a cloud-init.txt file which deploys docker and az cli in ubuntu 18.04-LTS which is required by the pipeline. This is the cloud-init file

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
  - mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/walinuxagent.service.d
  - echo "[Unit]\nAfter=cloud-final.service" > /etc/systemd/system/walinuxagent.service.d/override.conf
  - sed "s/After=multi-user.target//g" /lib/systemd/system/cloud-final.service > /etc/systemd/system/cloud-final.service
  - systemctl daemon-reload
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - apt-transport-https
  - ca-certificates
  - curl
  - gnupg-agent
  - software-properties-common
  - docker-ce
  - docker-ce-cli
groups:
 - docker

runcmd:
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
  - az --version
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
  - systemctl start docker
  - systemctl enable docker
  - docker pull einlinuus/testing:node
  - docker run -d -p 80:80 einlinuus/testing:node
  - sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
  - newgrp docker
  - sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
  - sudo systemctl restart docker
  - systemctl enable docker
```

The pipeline has 2 tasks

1. Docker to push the image to ACR **Docker@2**
   2)AZ-Cli job to run az cli commands **AzureCLI@2**

I notice that the VMSS agent VM is getting updated frequently for every task, even after the VM has attained running status, also the pipeline job is only 5 minutes, whereas i have set the idle standby time of the agent pool to 30 minutes.
[image]

Can anyone help me understand and prevent this? Thanks